# My bootstrap nav dropdown for small screens is not working

Tags: javascript, html

My nav dropdown button for smaller screens (phones and tablets) is not working. I have included the JS files but its still not working. Can anyone help determine why this is not wanting to connect with my js files.

> HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.mini.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">AffAttraction</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="advertisers.html">Advertisers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="publishers.html">Publishers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="">
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green">Login <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></button>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
<!-- Header -- >
<!-- Showcase -->
    <div id="showcase">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1><span class="highlight">Performance</span> Based Marketing</h1>
                <p>Do you have traffic? Let us help you monetize and profit from your websites, apps, games, blogs, and more!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Showcase -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.mini.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have included it at the top under my CSS links if you think that could be a problem. I also tried putting it under the body tag and the html tag. I am lost on what to do. Those files do exist!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code, replacing your local bootstrap stylesheets with the CDN version. When I loaded it, I crashed because jQuery was missing. After adding jQuery inside the head, it worked:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect the Bootstrap `CSS` and `JS` files on your `HTML`, you can easily do that with Bootstrap CDN.

Add this this to your `<head>` as Bootstrap Stylesheet
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

And this to your `<body>` as Bootstrap JavaScript link
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js

Also add JQuery for Bootstrap to work properly
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Using CDN is probably good but it also requires more time of grabbing the file and as well if the file is not there (Their server is down for some reason) then your site doesn't function properly. I will stick with the way I am using to make sure I never am dependent on another server.

Comment: Then make sure you add JQuery Script on top of Bootstrap Script in order to work :)